# Codec for coproducts with discriminator

Tags: scala, shapeless, circe

We're trying to have circe codecs for shapeless coproducts whith a class name as the discriminator :

```
object CoproductCodecWrong extends App {
  import io.circe.Codec
  import shapeless.{ :+:, CNil, Coproduct }
  import io.circe.shapes._
  import io.circe.literal._
  case class A()
  case class B(a: String)

  type AB = A :+: B :+: CNil
  case class H(ab: AB)

  implicit val encodeA: Codec[A] = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveCodec
  implicit val encodeB: Codec[B] = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveCodec

  implicit val hCodec: Codec.AsObject[H] = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveCodec[H]

  val hA: H = H(Coproduct[AB](A()))
  val hB: H = H(Coproduct[AB](B("q")))
}
```

It doesn't work because by default the encoder doesn't produce any information that allows to distinguish both cases:

```
println("hA:\n" + hCodec.apply(hA).toString())
println("hB:\n" + hCodec.apply(hB).toString())
...

hA:
{
  "ab" : {
    
  }
}
hB:
{
  "ab" : {
    "a" : "q"
  }
}
```

Decoding:

```
println(hCodec.decodeJson(json"""{"ab" : {}}"""))
println(hCodec.decodeJson(json"""{"ab" : {"a" : "q"}}"""))
...
Right(H(Inl(A())))
Right(H(Inl(A())))
```

It's always `A` that is found, which is very dangerous as it's working seemingly correctly but should be failing.

We've found a solution using Unions:

```
import io.circe.{ CursorOp, Decoder, DecodingFailure, Encoder }
import shapeless.ops.coproduct.Folder
import shapeless.ops.union.Values
import shapeless.union.Union
import shapeless.Poly1

type ABL = Union.`'A->A,'B->B`.T

object ABPoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit val atA: Case.Aux[A, ABL] = at[A] { z =>
    Union[ABL](A = z)
  }
  implicit val atB: Case.Aux[B, ABL] = at[B] { z =>
    Union[ABL](B = z)
  }
}

def coproductToLabeledCoproduct[Co <: Coproduct, Labeled <: Coproduct](t: Poly1)(
  implicit E: Encoder[Labeled],
  D: Decoder[Labeled],
  V: Values.Aux[Labeled, Co],
  F: Folder.Aux[t.type, Co, Labeled]
): Codec[Co] = {
  import io.circe.syntax._
  Codec.from(
    Decoder.instance { input =>
      input.focus
        .map(_.as[Labeled].map(x => shapeless.union.unionOps(x).values: Co))
        .getOrElse(Left(DecodingFailure("Should be available", { List(CursorOp.DownField("coproduct instance")) })))
    },
    Encoder.instance(a => a.fold(t).asJson)
  )
}

implicit val abToABL: Codec[AB] = coproductToLabeledCoproduct[AB, ABL](ABPoly)

implicit val hCodec: Codec.AsObject[H] = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveCodec[H]
```

The result of encoding/decoding is correct now:

```
hA:
{
  "ab" : {
    "A" : {
      
    }
  }
}
hB:
{
  "ab" : {
    "B" : {
      "a" : "q"
    }
  }
}
Right(H(Inl(A())))
Right(H(Inr(Inl(B(q)))))
```

But it's a bit complex, and hard to maintain for multiple classes.

Is there a better way?

EDIT:

`circe-generic-extras` doesn't work as it doesn't have a support for coproducts, only for `sealed traits` and `enums`. This gives the same result without a discriminator:

```
  implicit val configuration: Configuration = Configuration.default.withDiscriminator("tag")

  implicit val encodeA: Codec[A] = io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto.deriveConfiguredCodec
  implicit val encodeB: Codec[B] = io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto.deriveConfiguredCodec

  implicit val hCodec: Codec.AsObject[H] = io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto.deriveConfiguredCodec[H]
```

Comment: I think it can be done better (with shapeless) though I cannot say why you use shapeless in models in the first place. It is meant only as intermediate representation which is used by each library slightly different, and almost nobody supports it as something to work with directly.

Comment: It's generated by avrohugger for unions:
```
protocol ExampleProtocol {
    record A {
    }
    record B {
    }
    record H {
        union{A,B} ab;
    }

}
```
produces:
```
sealed trait ExampleProtocol extends Product with Serializable
final case class A() extends ExampleProtocol
final case class B() extends ExampleProtocol
final case class H(ab: A :+: B :+: CNil) extends ExampleProtocol
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `HLists` and `Coproducts` directly then I guess something  is broken in the code that requires that but I would probably use something like:

```
  import shapeless._
  import io.circe._
  import io.circe.syntax._

  class Discriminator(val fieldName: String, val classNameMapper: String => String)

  implicit def cnilCodec: Codec[CNil] =
    Codec.from(Decoder.instance[CNil](_ => Left(DecodingFailure("should never happen", Nil))), Encoder.instance(_ => ???))

  implicit def coproductCodec[LeftLabel, LeftType: Codec, Right <: Coproduct: Codec](
      implicit label: Witness.Aux[LeftLabel],
      discriminator: Discriminator
  ): Codec[FieldType[LeftLabel, LeftType] :+: Right] = {
    val thisLabel = discriminator.classNameMapper(label.value.toString)
    val decoder = Decoder.instance[FieldType[LeftLabel, LeftType] :+: Right] { hcursor =>
      hcursor
        .get[String](discriminator.fieldName)
        .leftMap(_.copy(message = s"Expected discriminator key ${discriminator.fieldName}"))
        .flatMap { thisLabel =>
          if (thisLabel == thisLabel) Decoder[LeftType].apply(hcursor).map(_.asInstanceOf[FieldType[LeftLabel, LeftType]]).map(Inl(_))
          else Decoder[Right].apply(hcursor).map(Inr(_))
        }
    }
    val encoder = Encoder.instance[FieldType[LeftLabel, LeftType] :+: Right] {
      case Inl(value) => (value: LeftType).asJson.deepMerge(Json.fromFields(Seq(discriminator.fieldName -> thisLabel.asJson)))
      case Inr(tail)  => tail.asJson
    }
    Codec.from(decoder, encoder)
  }
```

Whether it's simpler or more complicated it's a matter of taste.

For me personally this would be a red flag in deciding whether or not use the library in my code. Especially considering that you are forced to use shapeless directly with Circe, which supports sealed hierarchies out of the box.

I would use [Circe Generic Extras](https://github.com/circe/circe-generic-extras) with a sealed hierarchy.

It allows defining discriminator field name and format, providing support for auto- and semiauto derivation as well as macro annotations (`@ConfiguredJsonCodec` instead of `@JsonCodec`).

And then I would just translate this into this sad internal representation with:

```
def rewriteForCoproduct[A: Codec, ARepr <: Coproduct](implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, ARepr]): Codec[ARepr] =
  Codec.from(Codec[A].map[ARepr](gen.to), Codec[A].contramap[ARepr](gen.from))
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work AFAIK. I added a comment about `circe-generic-extras` library in my question.

Comment: Addressed that.

Comment: How I should use it? Not sure what's missing, it's not compiling...
```
      implicit val wA: Lt[String] = Witness("a")
      type a = wA.T
      implicit val wB: Lt[String] = Witness("b")
      type b = wB.T

      type aabb = FieldType[a, A] :+: FieldType[b, B] :+: CNil

      implicit val disc: Discriminator = new Discriminator("tag", ???)

      implicit val encodeA: Codec[A] = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveCodec
      implicit val encodeB: Codec[B] = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveCodec
      implicit val hCodec: Codec[H] = io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveCodec[H]
```